# Plain string encoded in latin1 somehow got messed up when converted to utf8. Now can't reverse back to latin1

Tags: encoding, utf-8, decoding, iso-8859-1

There are strings like this `VÃ¡zquez MontaÃ±ana` that can easily be decoded back using an online decoder. However, for some reason things got messed up and some plaintext ended up like this `SofÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â­a GarcÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©s DurÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¡`. When I try to decode this using Python, it gave the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte`. Is it impossible to reverse back? Do I have to do some guesswork or manual substitution? I'm not sure on what went wrong in the encoding process but it would help a lot if someone has a clue!

Answer (score 0):

It's a **triple** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python):

```
('SofÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â­a GarcÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©s DurÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¡'.
     encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
     encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
     encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'))
```

> ```
> 'Sofía Garcés Durá'
> ```

The former example is a simple mojibake:

```
'VÃ¡zquez MontaÃ±ana'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

> ```
> 'Vázquez Montañana'
> ```